# After first "once {next}" block, other same-scoped "once" blocks fail to execute

Tags: raku

My original plan was to use two `once {next}` blocks to skip the first two lines in a file (here emulating a as a multiline string):

```
for "A\nB\nC\n".lines() -> $line {
    once {next}
    once {next}
    put $line;
}
```

But it only skipped one iteration instead of two, outputting the following:

```
B
C
```

Instead of what I expected:

```
C
```

Apparently a single `once {next}` somehow cancels all remaining `once` blocks in the same scope:

```
my $guard = 3;

loop {
    last if $guard-- <= 0;
    once { next };
    once { put 'A: once ' };
    once { put 'A: once again' };
    put 'A: many ';
}

$guard = 3;
loop {
    last if $guard-- <= 0;
    once { put 'B: once ' };
    once { next };
    once { put 'B: once again' };
    put 'B: many ';
}

$guard = 3;
loop {
    last if $guard-- <= 0;
    once { put 'C: once ' };
    once { put 'C: once again' };
    once { next };
    put 'C: many ';
}
```

Outputting:

```
A: many
A: many
B: once
B: many
B: many
C: once
C: once again
C: many
C: many
```

(Example code here is a modified version of code at https://docs.raku.org/language/control#once).

Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding `once {next}` ?

Comment: By the way, a different approach to skipping the first X lines is to use an anonymous autoincrementing variable:
`for "A\nB\nC\n".lines() -> $line { next unless $++ > 1; put $line;}`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `once` construct semantics are associated with closure clones; since `for` is defined in terms of `map`, we can think of the block of the `for` loop being like a closure that is cloned once per loop, and that clone used for all iterations of the loop. The running of `once` blocks is done only on the first invocation of that closure clone. That is to say, it's a property at the level of the closure, not one of the `once` block itself.

The very same semantics apply to `state` variable initializers, which are defined in the same way (that is, they have `once` semantics). Therefore, this this also exhibits the same behavior:

```
for "A\nB\nC\n".lines() -> $line {
    state $throwaway-a = next;
    state $throwaway-b = next; # this `next` never runs
    put $line;
}
```

Alternative semantics could have been chosen, however a per-`once` (and so per-`state` variable) indicator would imply an extra piece of state is needed for each of them.

So far as the original problem goes, a clearer solution would be:

```
for "A\nB\nC\n".lines().skip(2) -> $line {
    put $line;
}
```